# Webpage’s slide show (Image Viewer) doesn’t work, when I create from already developed template

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash

I create a web template in Dreamweaver 8; in this template I added a slide show (Image Viewer). This template is working fine in browsers and slide show also playing, but when I create the new web page from this template, and then the slide show not playing, there is an error message display.
message is below:

“A script in this movie is causing Adobe Flash Player 10 to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer may become unresponsive. Do you want to abort the script?  Yes  or  No ”

I keep getting this message again and again. When I say no, it asks me again and again, when I say yes then I can't see whats playing.
I also Restart the computer, but don’t work.

Please help me.

What can I do to fix this?

I will appreciated for your help in advance.

Comment: sorry, but with no source code and a vague description, its almost impossible to assist. which flash embed gallery are you using? any links?

Comment: The problem is probably with the embedded swf, but, as Alec said, it's impossible to help you without more info.

Comment: Need code in order to help. Saying it again for emphasis...

Answer (score 0):

man!

use Dreamweaver CS5 from 2010 and **not** Dreamweaver 8 from 2005 year!!

Comment: ! I can’t afford Dreamweaver CS5, it is expensive, and there is trial version for 30 days.
Do you have an any link, where I download free Dreamweaver CS5 with key? (not trial version). thanks

Comment: you should google ot thepiratebay to find it. one more thing download archive http://depositfiles.com/files/4n8e3r3l2 and replace TestBone.swf with your swf file and change the name to TestBone.swf too and try to run included html file. but I don't think it will help, its about html wrapper that people talks above.